# Ideals in an unfamiliar ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking to find a principal ideal in the ring $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}]$. However, I can't wrap my head around what this looks like. I understand the notation for polynomial rings (i.e. $\mathbb{C}[x]$); is this something similar?

In terms of finding a principal ideal, what types of elements in the ring could I use? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably the *group algebra* of the infinite cyclic group. We have a variable $x_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$, take their $\Bbb C$-linear combinations, with the rule $x_nx_m=x_{n+m}$.

Comment: *In terms of finding a principal ideal, what types of elements in the ring could I use?*  This is a _really bizarre_ question. Every element generates its own principal ideal. It is not hard to "find" them: they are all plainly available, and there is no "type" of element that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group algebra $\mathbb C[\mathbb Z]$ is isomorphic to the ring of [Laurent polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) over $\mathbb C$ in one variable, that is, $\mathbb C[x^{-1},x]$.  The isomorphism should be obvious:  $z\mapsto x^z$ extends linearly to an isomorphism.

A $\mathbb C$-basis for the ring of Laurent polynomials is $\{x^i\mid i\in\mathbb Z\}$, and so the elements look like finite linear combinations.

It is worth noting that this ring is also isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x]$ localized at the multiplicative set $S=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$

> In terms of finding a principal ideal, what types of elements in the ring could I use?

It is a principal ideal domain, since it is the localization of a principal ideal domain. Each element in the ring generates a principal ideal, and there are no other ideals.